# Can we replace surface stabilizers of CuS nanoparticles with a solid matrix?

Tags: precipitation, nanotechnology, surfactants

Is there a method to simultaneously remove surface stabilizer molecules from $\ce{CuS}$ (copper monosulfide) nanoparticles and form inclusions of the nanoparticles into a solid crystal growing from a liquid suspension (aqueous?) of the particles in a saturated solution of a material forming the matrix as it precipitates?

If anybody happens to know several methods, the one that achieves the highest number density of inclusions without clumping of $\ce{CuS}$ particles is preferable.